# creating a fragment from a fragment without using fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a fragment with code like this

```
SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
    .commit();
```

However, since I changed "extends Fragment" to "PreferenceFragment" in my SettingFragment I use

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {}
```

this line is giving me the error that my second argument "fragment" requires "android.support.v4.app.Fragment" After adding this lib it's still not working

```
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
```

It looks like my fragmentManager is confusing about my fragment... Is there a way to solve this problem or even not using the fragmentManager? Thanks

Comment: You have to do more than just add the lib it's asking for. You have to make sure `PreferenceFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as well.

Comment: Hi @NoChinDeluxe Thanks for reply. Could you be more specific? How do I make sure PreferenceFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PreferenceFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment`. In order to use the support `FragmentManager`, you must use a class that extends the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, as @NoChinDeluxe suggested.

I suggest using the [v7 Preference Support Libarary](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/package-summary.html):

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.0.0'
```

This library includes the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` class, which extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Therefore you can extend this class, instead of `PreferenceFragment` to use your `SettingsFragment` with the support `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for your answer, the error is gone now. But I need to somehow add a preference theme, could you tell me how to set it in my code? Thank you

Comment: @XiaoshengWilsonWu You should be able to set the theme for your preference screens in the theme you are using for the activity. In this theme you can set the `android:preferenceStyle` and/or the `android:preferenceScreenStyle`.

Comment: Hi Brayan, are you talking about AndroidManifest.xml file? Since I use a fragment to call the preference, I think I have alrealy specified the theme in MainActivity... Do I need to write code in other files?

Comment: @XiaoshengWilsonWu Yes, you should specify the theme for the Activity that is holding your `SettingsFragment` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. The only other code you would have to write is in your `styles.xml` file, and specify the styles for the preference screens in the theme you use in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `SettingsFragment` inherits from `PreferenceFragment`, that means it essentially *is* a `PreferenceFragment`. This means that whatever `PreferenceFragment` inherits from, your `SettingsFragment` will also be that as well.

So the solution is to make sure your `PreferenceFragment` inherits the correct `Fragment` class. In other words, at the top of your `PreferenceFragment` file, you should have `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` and no other Fragment import. That will make your `PreferenceFragment` a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, which will then make your `SettingsFragment` that as well, which will allow it to work in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.